# N persons in K rooms, expected population of most crowded room

Tags: probability, combinatorics

There are N people. Each of them randomly and independently select one of K rooms, with uniform distribution.

Seems to me obvious that the expected population of each room will be N/K.

What will be the expected population of the most crowded room?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balls_into_bins http://mathoverflow.net/questions/146418/expectation-of-maximum-of-uniform-multinomial-distribution http://www.ic.unicamp.br/~celio/peer2peer/math/balls-into-bins.pdf